# Bot manipulation using the console in TF2

Tags: team-fortress-2

When in offline practice, how can you manipulate bots so that they will follow rules when picking their classes (and thus allowing the player to enable / disable classes etc)
Namely I'm wanting:

To be able to "toggle" (or turn on / off) some classes i.e disable medic class for bots

and

To force at least X number of bots to be Y class i.e forcing the bots to always have at least 1 spy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In console, type `tf_bot_add <count> <class> <team> <difficulty>`.

Example: `tf_bot_add 2 demoman red normal`

All substitutions should be self explanatory.  Difficulty is `easy`, `normal`, `hard`, `advanced`, or `expert`. If you wish to spawn a Heavy, you'll have to use `heavyweapons`, there is no special class command for any of the others. Team is `red` or `blue`.

As for forcing them to have no medics, and one spy, the best thing to do is set up the teams with the previous command, then type `tf_bot_keep_class_after_death 1`. Which will prevent bots from changing classes.

To get rid of bots, type `tf_bot_kick <name>`.  Ex: `tf_bot_kick foo` if a bot's name is foo.

Comment: More on the command here: http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Bots. Also note that "demo" is called "demoman" for the purposes of the command.